# Drupal user data storage location

Tags: mysql, drupal

Where does Drupal 7 store user data? I believe our client has been inserting bad data (incorrect characters) copied from MS Word into their Drupal install (for their user list).

How do I export/look at the users to see if any bad characters are in them?

I'm taking a look at the structure of the database in MySQL and I'm not seeing any clear table with the data in it. Is it contained in only one, or multiple tables?

Comment: What do you mean user data? Do you mean fields on the user entity?

Comment: Yes. I want all the information on a given user.

Comment: What kind of information are you referring to? Name? Signature? What specifically?

Comment: Name, anything that a user or admin would input when they put a new person in. Basically anything that allows any sort of characters inserted in freely.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `users` table. Any fields added to a user will be in `field_data_field_user...`

Comment: phpMyAdmin limits the viewable list of tables. Since drupal has many tables, use the filter and type "users" so you don't have to go through pages of tables to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User data is stored in multiple tables one of which is the `users` table. Any fields that have been added to the user entity will be in the `field_data_field_user...` table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpMyAdmin or similar interface, you will only be able to immediately see a portion of the tables Drupal has. Use the filter to find "users" and the Users table will appear in the list. There is only one table if there were no modifications for custom user fields.

You can export the table as a CSV and open in a spreadsheet interface, such as Excel; though Excel is not always friendly with UTF-8 if it's not set up to display it. Or you can save the file as a .SQL and view it in a database viewer such as SQLite in Firefox.